# Local website unreachable from Android phone

Tags: networking

I have a local media player running on a raspberry pi that that provides a web interface via WiFi. This interface is sometimes unreachable (via hostname or IP) from my Android phone while it is still accessible from my laptop and from an iPhone in the same network.

I am posting this here since I suspect a routing problem. The WiFi network consists of 3 access points and a home router that also provides DHCP etc.

How do I analyze this? Any ideas on the issue?

Comment: Did you try `ping` to router and the website host?

Comment: Ping and traceroute from the Android device both fail with a timeout. All other devices on the network are reachable, though. What's even more strange is that sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.